# Magento include src folder have lot of php file

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9 in my website. Recently someone hack my website after that i noticed in root folder: `includes/src` folder have lot's of .php files. All the php files are related to some extension. That available in both extension as well as `includes/src`.

I don't know it's required files or not can you please any one give some idea about that

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The files are created  at ***includes/src*** because of In current time or may in past,compiler s enabled  on system that why it create lot of file.

As per as magento,When a compiler is enabled on system then magento is take  it all enable modules class's and  put in `includes/src`.Thus make site faster in loaded time

Comment: Ok can i keep all those file or delete all the files

Comment: Yes, you can safely delete the compiled php src files.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. But i think you should use inbox Magento tools in  shell folder.
1. You need to disable compiler via admin or by shell command
cd /var/www/magento_root/ or else
php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable

2. After that check the status of compiler 
   php -f shell/compiler.php -- state

You can see something like this
Compiler Status:          Disabled
Compilation State:        Compiled
Collected Files Count:    9165
Compiled Scopes Count:    4

As you can see your compiler process disabled now, but you have "Collected Files" in magento_root/include/src

3. For remove these files and folder use next:
   php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear
4. Finally check status again:
   php -f shell/compiler.php -- state

Now you see 
Compiler Status:          Disabled
Compilation State:        Not Compiled
Collected Files Count:    0
Compiled Scopes Count:    0

Then look at the magento_root, folder include doesn't exist.