# Extension Store src folder

Tags: magento-1.9

My all installed extension **folder's**  and **File's**  stored in this location

```
/domain/includes/src
```

If i delete any problem will come or why it's storing in this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files are created at `includes/src` because of In current time or may in past,compiler s enabled on system that why it create lot of file.

Thus make site faster in loaded time.

see these links [link1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86929/magento-include-src-folder-have-lot-of-php-file) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588912/magento-modules-duplicated-into-include-src)

Comment: Ok why it's storing src folder

Comment: sorry my mistake this is concern with compiler.

Comment: it mean to say enable compilation right

Comment: no it mean it is generated because of compilation mode is enable or enable in past..

Comment: Yes i understood if i delete all file any problem will come

Comment: http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=49 these are solution for that.

Comment: Ok i will check it i have 1 doubt

Comment: what doubt you have in mind?

Comment: In my site have lots of exception.log is there. It will create problem

Comment: it will make website loading time slow and website got more space day by day you have to remove that log errors.

Comment: i need to fix that log error or not a problem

Comment: you have to fix that..

Comment: but it have lot's of error it will create problem in future

Comment: did you face these problemhttp://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104095/my-phtml-code-not-working-in-another-phtml